# Metric, tangent and contangent spaces

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces, manifolds, tangent-spaces, co-tangent-space

I have a lot of confusion understanding manifolds, charts, tangent and cotangent vector spaces…

Please let me know where I am wrong.

Let’s take a flat minkosky space in 4 dimensions and call it $M$, and take a standard orthonormal basis $\{e_\mu\}$.

I can think of this space as a flat manifold, so I can build tangent and cotangent spaces for every point $p$ on top of it. Because of it being flat I can identify the tangent space (which would have as standard basis $\partial_\mu$) as the space M itself (so $\partial_\mu$ and $e_\mu$ coincide). (How can I prove this?)

So now I have the components of a point on M as coordinates $x=x^\mu e_\mu$ and components of a vector on $T_pM$ as $V=V^\mu e_\mu$ with the same basis $e^\mu$.
Because I can identify $T_pM$ with $M$ for every $p$ therefore under a basis transformation:
$$x^i=\lambda^i_j x^j$$
also the components of the tangent spaces will change in the same way:
$$V^i=\lambda^i_j V^j$$
(Couldn’t I get the same result by stating that every vector in the tangent space transforms with the Jacobian of the transformation?)

In the end I have two different objects (vector on $M$ and vector in $T_pM$) that behave in the same way under a transformation.
Is this correct?

Thank you for your help and sorry for my confusion.

Comment: I think I follow your post until $x_i$ suddenly shows up. What's that? (Also, it's not really $y^i = \lambda_j^i x^j$, and $g$ is not a 2 form).

Comment: How are the $y^i$ linear combinations of the $x^j$? This would be very special charts. I recommend you to try to understand these concepts thoroughly, for example, in Spivak's Vol I, or in Lee's book.  Also, it's usually the other way around: a metric $g$ gives you an isomorphism between tangent and cotangent bundles. In general, they are not isomorphic, a vector bundle and it's dual.

Comment: "Flat Minkowski space" is a metric concept. Everything to do with tangent and cotangent spaces only depends on the underlying smooth manifold and in this case you're just looking at regular old $\mathbb{R}^4$.

Comment: Okk thanks for your correction :)

Comment: So if I have $R^4$ with Minkowki metric, everything I wrote is correct or not?

Comment: What is your definition of a flat manifold? According to my definition, what you say is wrong.